# Nodemon: how to send / get last changed filename in my script

Tags: nodemon

I try (using nodemon) to find a way to send the name of last changed file name to the child script or to get them inside in script.
As command line argument?
From a log file?
Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Require nodemon in your project, and listen for the restart event: https://github.com/remy/nodemon/blob/master/doc/events.md#states this will give you a complete list of files that restarted the script.

If you just want to log it out (in the terminal so you know), you can use verbose mode:

```
nodemon --verbose
```